# Angular UI Grid - how to change view on row select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a grid displaying data. I want to be able to route to a new view with a click of a grid row.  Right now I am unable to even register a row click/selection.  I have tried in my grid definition:

```
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi ) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.selection.on.onRowSelectionChanged($scope, function (rows) {
            $scope.mySelections = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();                
        });
    },
```

with a call to mySelections in the html:

```
    <p>{{mySelections}}</p>
```

this results in error : Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.   However, I can't tell what is 'undefined'.

I have also tried a separate function:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
        alert(row.isSelected);
        //$scope.mySelections = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();                
    });
};
```

but it returns the same error.

I have added ui.grid and ui.grid.selection to my angular.module.  I would love to find an actual example of using rowselect to link to a new page, but I have to find anything.

Comment: `gridApi.selection` is undefined, because that's the only object invoking the method `on`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.

Suggests that the `selection` property is not available on your `gridApi` object, i'de double check if you really added the dependencies the right way:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.grid.selection'
]);
```

Next, calling `gridApi.selection.on.onRowSelectionChanged` won't work because the method is called `rowSelectionChanged` not `onRowSelectionChanged`. You've got that right in your second example. For the rest your code seems ok, perhaps there's something wrong in the rest of your grid definition. Here's one that works with an example using `ui.router` for view change:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (rows) {
            var selection = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
            $state.go('item', {item: selection[0]});
        });
    }
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rs9M6pJd83vK8syr3W9g?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the "ui-grid-selection" attribut to your DIV :

```html
 <div class="gridStyle" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ... ></div>
```